# how to use aws unload command to unload data from AWS Redshift to s3?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

How can I unload data from the Redshift to S3? I was reading the following document but where can I use this command?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html

```
unload ('select * from venue')   
to 's3://mybucket/tickit/unload/venue_' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';
```

is it a bash command or py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execute this query against your Redshift cluster using your SQL connection.

This is executed in the similar way to how you would run the `COPY` command.

Ensure that the IAM role in question has been attached to the Redshift cluster and that it has permissions to call `S3:PutObject` for your bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to your cluster. For example, using workbench:

- [Connect to your cluster by using SQL Workbench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html)

There are also other ways, as listed in the following link:

- [Connecting to an Amazon Redshift cluster using SQL client tools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-to-cluster.html)